# Not able to identify an element in Selenium Webdriver (cookies pop-up on skynews)

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I have tried all the methods including xpath but I am still not able to click on the Accept button on cookies popup on https://www.news.sky.com

Tried css selector, xpath, frame etc everything.

Here is my code:

public class Browser {

```
WebDriver driver;

public void browser_open() {
    
    String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath+"\\Drivers\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
}

    public void navigate() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.get("http://news.sky.com");
    
        //Thread.sleep(5000);
    
        driver.switchTo().frame("sp_message_iframe_368417");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/button[1]")).click();
}
}
```

Please can someone help me on this?

I have already gone through a lot of posts on this and other forums but couldn't find an solution.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: Use relative xpath rather than absolute xpath. Try using this for the button xpath //button[text()='Accept'] and remove your code related to switch frame.

Comment: If i remove my code related to switch frame. I get an error "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@title='Accept']"}"

However, if i leave it then it works but after 30-40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the xpath of `//button[@title='Accept']` for what it's worth.

It's possible the switch to doesn't work because the element doesn't exist yet in the frame.

```
    driver.switchTo().frame("sp_message_iframe_368417");
    
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@title='Accept']")));        
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@title='Accept']")).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I am getting this warning on WebDriverWait - "The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, long) is deprecated"

and the problem still persists. Any other ideas?